# Android: How to scroll RecyclerView only by y-axis

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a RecyclerView and TextView in a Fragment.  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instantiates my Fragments for parent ViewPager.

When I try to scroll to right or left on TextViews, it works great, but RecyclerViews intercept my swipes and ViewPager can't switch Fragments.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `mRecycleView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` for `RecycleView`.

Comment: What is the LayoutManager did you set to your recyclerView ?

Comment: just a simple `LinearLayoutManager`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I write `centerList.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` in fragment's `OnCreateView` it still don't work.

Comment: Have you set Vertical scrolling for your LinearLayoutManager ?

Comment: I use this code: `centerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`